# How to append values of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, nsmutabledictionary

I have NSMUtableDictionary wich includes multiple dictionary.I am doing XML parsing of that data.
Now when to return the dictionary data it gives me the last dictionary value.
Here is my code:

```
    for(CXMLNode* child in [element children]) {
        id v = [Soap deserialize:child];
        if(v == nil) { 
            v = [NSNull null]; 
        }

        [d setObject:v forKey:[child name]];
    }
    NSLog(@"dData=%@",d);
    return d;
```

when i return the value of d it gives me the last dictionary value.
Please suggest me the way to solve this problem.
Thank you

Comment: Please paste [child name] output.

Comment: Where is `d` declared? Can you show use that code as well? Also I hope that the code you have pasted here is exact code and `d` is not allocated and initialized inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it's possible that the [child name] is not unique.  Why not NSLog(@"child name = %@", [child name]); before you set the object and make sure that name is unique?

Also, you can set a breakpoint anywhere and the type:

po d

in the debugger to list the contents of d.

Comment: I check the NSLog of [child name] alltime it gives unique values.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot insert `NSNull` object into `NSMutableDictionary` as a dictionary. This will indicate your end of dictionary whenever your First `NSNull` object is appended in dictionary (d). Check whether the child coming in `CXMLNode` exists in all the cases. Else this is your root cause of problem.

Considering Data coming into `CXMLNode` is from internet then first check whether that service is sending proper data or not.

Comment: This is incorrect.  You can't put **nil** objects in a dictionary.  The *whole point* of `NSNull` is that instances of it are valid objects for putting in collections to signify a missing value.